# Make a computed Age dropdown with VueJs

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue! I want to build a simple select field with value:
"0" => "No age limit", 6 ->90

So, I would like to build 6 to 90 with a v-for, but I don't know exactly how to do it, and still to have the initial "no age limit"

Any idea how to do it???

Comment: You are clearly familiar with how stack overflow works... so where's the code?

Comment: Existing code didn't help that much in this case, because I had no idea how to code it.... resulted to be much simpler!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shoud be something like this:

```html
<body>
  <select>
    <option value="0">No age limit</option>
    <option :value="n+6" v-for="n in 85">{{n+6}}</option>
  </select>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.21/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: 'body'
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I was complicating myself a lot with this one...

Comment: how do you make it editable as well ?